# JQuery - Hamburger menu creation with animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

```
 <div class="hamburger">
        hamburger
        </div>
```

Hey guys I'm trying to create a hamburger menu like the menu in this link that I provided. i have nothing only html. And I don't know hoe create this? You guys can help me I think. Did you find anything like this? Or can you tell me how to do this?
https://www.hugeinc.com/us

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll have 2 elements there - the button ('**H**' on the link you provided), and the navigation - list of links, that is hidden by default. Clicking on the '**H**' button would show the navigation menu (and change text from H to Huge, or whatever you want).

```
<style>
    .hidden {
       display:none;
    }
</style>

<div class="hamburger">
    H
</div>
<div class="navigation hidden">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>

<script>
   $('.hamburger').click(function(){
     $('.navigation').toggleClass('hidden');
     $(this).text()==='H'?$(this).text('Huge'):$(this).text('H');
   });
</script>
```

That's the basic idea how it would work. You can adjust it to your needs and style it how you want it to look.

*(I haven't tested it, so it may contain some syntax errors - but the idea stands).*